# Story ident : Graphic novel about people building a spaceship to explore other worlds?

Tags: story-identification, comics, spaceship

I'm trying to remember the name of a graphic novel I read in Barnes and Noble several years ago (probably 2010 - 2012). It was full color.

They were trying to build a spaceship to explore other worlds, I think it was because of global warming and rising sea levels. Something about America being completely uninhabited maybe? I do remember that white people were considered second-class citizens to their Asian counterparts.

I've been searching through all the independent comic publisher's websites, but I can't seem to find it.

Comment: Can you give us more to go on: Was it an American Comic or a Manga Import?  Can you describe - The ships? The Art Style? The Character Designs? The Uniforms Worn? The Cover of the Book?  Really any more detail would be of help.

Comment: It sounds a little like the background to Warren Ellis' Orbiter. Except that's about a ship returning to such an earth, rather than a spaceship being built. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbiter_(comics)#/media/File:Orbiter_tpb_cover.jpg